# Getting 3 high errors when tring to deploy nodejs app to Heroku involving QS package

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm

From an nppm audit i am getting 3 High errors with Q.

npm audit fix does not resolve them.

They seem to be able to be resolved with a high version than 6 but i have version 6.5.2. installed and still getting the errors.

Any help on what might be causing this or a workaround would be great!

Error 1:   High            Denial-of-Service Extended Event Loop Blocking

```
  Package         qs

  Patched in      >= 1.x


  Dependency of   node-modules

  Path            node-modules > request > qs
```

Error 2:  High            Denial-of-Service Memory Exhaustion

```
  Package         qs


  Patched in      >= 1.x

  Dependency of   node-modules

  Path            node-modules > request > qs
```

Error 3:   High            Prototype Pollution Protection Bypass

```
  Package         qs

  Patched in      >=6.0.4 <6.1.0 || >=6.1.2 <6.2.0 || >=6.2.3 <6.3.0 ||
                  >=6.3.2

  Dependency of   node-modules

  Path            node-modules > request > qs
```

Adding package.json

```
{
  "name": "jpkmdfpackage",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.12"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://git.heroku.com/magic-order-application.git"
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/cryptiles": "^5.0.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "connect-ensure-login": "^0.1.1",
    "cryptiles": "^4.1.2",
    "ejs": "^3.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.1.0",
    "express-session": "^1.17.0",
    "git": "^0.1.5",
    "mongodb": "^3.5.5",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.6",
    "morgan": "^1.9.1",
    "node-gyp": "^6.1.0",
    "node-modules": "^1.0.1",
    "node-pre-gyp": "^0.14.0",
    "nodegit": "^0.26.5",
    "npm-lifecycle": "^3.1.5",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "description": "MagicOrder Application"
}
```

Comment: Can you show us your package.json file ? bcs i had to modify it to get rid of some heroku errors before deploying the app

Comment: Thanks @SalahEddineMakdour added in now.

Comment: well, i was gonna check the start and test scripts but they r actually fine, i just don't know, maybe u could try reinstalling all the packages again it might work